# Catch F11 pressed when the flash app is not in focus?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, interop, fullscreen

hi i have a website which has a video playing.

what i want is when my browser going into a full screen mode i want to only show my video.

when i press <kbd>F11</kbd> by click  on the address bar / click on the browser window and press <kbd>F11</kbd>
my browser goes into the full screenmode.But i dont understand that <kbd>F11</kbd> is played.

Is there a event from my browser to Html code that i can use to understand that my browser has gone into fullscreen mode ?

Thanks

Sohil

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function displayUnicodeKeyValue(e){
     var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
     alert(unicode);

     if(unicode === 112) {
          //Yay, F11 was pressed, put code here to handle it.
               }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/keylistener.html

Easy to use key listener that will not only capture the key event, but stop it from propogating up to the browser.  I have gotten this to work with CRTL+O.